# In Eclipse Debugger, getting the index location of a variable in an embeded list hierachy

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging, arraylist

Is anyone familiar with a debugging option that has the feature? I have a list of items in a JComboBox deeply embedded in a swing app that is buried withing multiple lists. Is there is away to find the index of these items in the Eclipse Debugger without writing code? I could manually write down the index of every list, but I'm looking for an easier way to tell me that this location is at parent[2].layer[0].child[3].layer[1].child[0].combobox[4].item[5]
without looking scrolling through the variable list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When debugging, in the variables/Expressions pane, at the top right there should be a button with an arrow going to the right called "Show Logical Structure".

If you tick/untick that it should change the display of list structures. It might help you out.